# Helper functions for ECC operations in Monero

Tags: source

1 - Where exactly the base-point `G` is defined?  for example the function ge_scalarmult_base should multiply by `G`, but in the implementation I don't see any reference, where `G` is initlized.

2- Where can I find helpers functions that give the following abilities:

1. Convert an Int to scalar (ge/fe).
2. Multiplication of two points over the curve.
3. Print ECC point from the type `RCT::key`.
4. Print scalar from the type `RCT::key`.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

1. https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/crypto/crypto-ops-data.c
2. There are 2 places these ops are found, firstly https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/crypto/crypto-ops.c which has the lower level c code and https://github.com/monero-project/monero/tree/master/src/ringct which has some c++ wrappers.

Comment: could you be more specific (function names/inputs/outputs)? the second reference you mentioned lack documentation and I don't seem to be able to understand them properly.

Comment: Converting an into to a scalar is just copying the bytes to a char array (as that is the data type for a scalar, an array of bytes). Multiplication of 2 points is an odd request as you would normally multiply a point by a scalar. Printing an rct::key is just printing the key.bytes field (which you'd likely want to print as hex using printf).